# Direct object or directional を

Tags: particles

> 高校を卒業してから弟はいろんな会社を転々とした.

Translation: After graduation my brother wandered from job to job.

Here, are both を's (高校**を**卒業 and いろんな会社**を**転々とした) used in the direct object sense or in the directional "leaving" sense? For the latter: my brother graduated *from* his school; he wandered *from* job to job.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar w/ the "leaving" pattern.  In the Japanese sense, they are both D.O.  He graduated.  Graduated what?  graduated high school.  He wandered.  Wandered what?  Wandered various companies.  "From/Leaving" doesn't come in until you translate it.

Comment: That comment isn't especially helpful—there are syntactic and semantic distinctions to be made without any translation into English.

Comment: Kiss-o-matic: As shown by brocoli's link, there are multiple distinct usages of を. The most important are probably the first three: direct object, movement from a source (what I meant by "leaving"), and movement through/along an area respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 高校を卒業

Japanese 卒業する takes institutions as **direct object**, unlike English *graduate from*. I remember how my English teacher was telling us not to say something like "graduate high school".

#### いろんな会社を転々とした

Your translation is correct, but を corresponds to "from ... to ..." in your sentence. Most Japanese movement verbs take **locations where they take place** with を. I guess most of the native speakers couldn't tell the usage from the direct object one. [A dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/239138/m0u/%E3%82%92/) says:

> 移動の意を表す動詞に応じて、動作の経由する場所を示す。…を通って。「山道―行く」「廊下―走る」「山―越す」
>   Indicates location where the action pass through, used with a verb of motion; through/via ...; "go *on* the mountain road", "run *in* a hall", "go across the mountain"

P.S.
Maybe it's more understandable to assume all these verbs have invisible English prepositions built in, like 行く "to go-on", 走る "to run-in", 転々とする "to wander-around" etc.

Comment: Thanks, now I have more usages of を to learn!
Aside: Is 転々とする considered a "する/compound verb" like 勉強する? Do 転々とする and 転々する mean the same thing?

Comment: Your 勉強する is a verb attached to a noun. 転々 is a description of state "flip-flop", so it's not the case. It's difficult to put shortly, but 転々とする and 転々する have slightly different meanings, and only the former one is an idiomatic expression.